# How to get objects from the image and get a pixel map of the image?

Tags: python, opencv

So i have an image with a red circle and blue circle, with black obstacles on a white background. I would like to get 2d Matrix of the image and map my objects in a 2d matrix with different numbers ( 1 for red circle area; 2 for black; and 3 for obstacles). How can I implement it?

Comment: if you have an image, show it. -- have you heard of "segmentation"? cv.inRange? connected components or contours? -- can I interest you in the tutorials on https://docs.opencv.org/ ?

Comment: Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).